# How to make Confirm Password field in Shopify?

Tags: forms, passwords, registration, shopify

I'm creating a Shopify website, and I'm currently working on the customer registration form. I need to make a Confirm Password field. Does anybody know how to do this in Shopify?

Comment: I figured it out! Here's my solution: http://pastebin.com/NkK0jYne

Answer (score 2):

Just Got it working on my register page:

The two password fields:

```
  <div id="create_password_container">
    <label for="password">Your Password<em>*</em></label>
    <input type="password" value="" name="customer[password]" id="create_password" {% if form.errors contains "password" %} class="error"{% endif %}>
  </div>

  <div id="password_confirm_container">
    <label for="password_confirmation">Password Confirmation</label> <span class="password-match">PASSWORDS DO NOT MATCH</span>
    <input type="password" value="" name="customer[password_confirmation]" id="password_confirm" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    $('form#create_customer').submit(function(e) { 

    if ( $('#create_password').val() === $('#password_confirm').val()) {
      //alert('Password Good!!');

    } else {
      $('.password-match').fadeIn("slow");
      e.preventDefault(); // stops our form from submitting
    }
});
```

The CSS for the password not-matching message:

```
.password-match {font-size: 12px; color: #f1152f; display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

When customers receive the link to their activation they are prompted for both a password and a password confirmation. Failing that - you can add an extra input (password confirmation) and then do a simple comparison with javascript. Something like:

```
        .... <label for="password" class="login">{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}</label>
        <input type="password" value="" name="customer[password]" id="password" class="large password" size="30" />


        <label for="password-confirm" class="login">{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}</label>
        <input type="password" value="" name="customer[password-confirm]" id="password-confirm" class="large password" size="30" /> ....
```

and then with jquery - something like

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stops our form from submitting
    if ( $('#password').val() === $('#password-confirm').val()) {
     $('form').submit();
    }
});
```

That was done off the top of my head - so not tested. It should compare the two password strings - and if they match, allow the form to submit. Of course - you'll probably want to do stuff like show a pop up... alert or message to say your passwords don't match etc. In which case:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stops our form from submitting
    if ( $('#password').val() === $('#password-confirm').val()) {
     $('form').submit();
    } else {
    // put your validation message in here - this could be showing an element... or showing an alert etc
        alert("Your passwords don't match dummy!")
    }
});
```

You could just as easily do

```
 $( ".errorMessage" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
      $(this).hide();
  });
```

instead of the alert - but you'd need to make sure you have a div with a class of .errorMessage that contains your error message :)

Comment: I tried taking your third snippet of code and adding it to scripts.js (with the variables altered accordingly), but I found the following error in the console: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded." Any idea what that's all about?

Comment: Hi Arial, Could you paste your code in here - and a link to the page where you get the error

Comment: I can't link you to the page because it's password protected, but here is my code:

`$('form#create_customer').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // stops our form from submitting

    if (confirmPassword == password) {
      console.log("passwords match");
     $('form#create_customer').submit();
    } else {
      return false;
      console.log("passwords don't match");
    // put your validation message in here - this could be showing an element... or showing an alert etc
        alert("Your passwords don't match dummy!");
    }
  });`

Comment: Could you also add your html? Why not drop it all into jsbin?

Comment: Also - your return false isn't needed.... the return false actually exits the function before you get to your alert...  Have a look at this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yv20kamw/